# Change the HTTP status blog links to HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-review, ssl, maintenance, stackstatus

In the "We are currently offline for maintenance" page, the status blog link is a HTTP one. Please change it to HTTPS.

[image: Image of Status Page]

Also, in the header which is shown when the site is in read-only mode, the status blog link is HTTP. Please change it to HTTPS.

[image]

---

Update (29/07/2022):

The link is not updated even after [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378941).

[image]

---

Update (15/06/2023):

The link is still HTTP.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, we are aware we need to update all outward-facing links and use `https://www.` consistently, as mentioned here: [The StackStatus website does not resolve without a preceding "www" in the URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381162/165455).

Answer (score 8):

As I pointed out [in this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382679/dead-link-in-offline-for-maintenance-page#comment1281207_382679), all of the offline/maintenance pages have been updated as of today to point to https://www.stackstatus.net.

Short of manually taking the site offline, I can't directly demonstrate this to you. But here is some evidence:

> [image: Evidence from a PR]

Note that we still can't fix existing inbound links on other systems that leave out the `www`, as explained here:

- [The StackStatus website does not resolve without a preceding "www" in the URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381162/165455)

...but we did fix all of the links inside of our systems back in September, as explained here:

- [What happened to old postmortems on stackstatus.net?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382403/165455)

Comment: Thanks for fixing it! Meanwhile, I will wait for the site to go offline ;)

Comment: @RandomPerson I'd love to take credit, but I only created the ticket. :-)

Comment: I just got the "Offline for maintenance" message on Stack Overflow and the link was **http**://www.stackstatus.net. It wasn't the normal page with a blank background, but rather the one with a background full of code and symbols (which I had never seen with this message before. Edit: or maybe I'm misremembering because I mostly see it on MSE?). Unfortunately, I couldn't take a screenshot because the page automatically refreshed when I ran to answer the door.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine I'm not sure, I checked source control and all the URLs have been changed. It's possible that not all of the files have been built and deployed all the way through to production yet, or that you were served up an old/cached version of a static page. On the plus side, _that_ link (`http + www`) will redirect just fine to https - the truly problematic URL is `http + _no_ www`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Oh, I believe it was without `www` because it did _not_ redirect. I just copied the URL from the answer and forgot to remove that part. Anyway, I'll try to take a screenshot of the source if it happens again.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Here, I just got his on MSO: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3AgS.png. The link is still `http://stackstatus.net/`.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine I didn't forget about this. We are still investigating, it seems the static artifacts (offline HTML pages) were definitely updated in source control, but didn't get updated as part of the deployment.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Should the status tag be changed?

Comment: @RandomPerson Sure, but it's not going to change the priority, and I don't know that it will matter if they sort it out before our next maintenance.

Comment: @RandomPerson (And to be transparent, trying to publish changes to these static files for the first time since moving to .net core and overhauling our CI/CD has revealed an issue that is simple on its own - improper handling of a boolean during handoff - but needs to be corrected carefully because it has wide impact.)