# Change status blog address to https://www.stackstatus.net/ in the offline for maintenance page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, maintenance, stackstatus

When the site if offline for maintenance, we see this:

[image: offline for maintenance message linking to status blog]

The status blog currently links to https://stackstatus.net which is down for some people (myself included) for reasons described in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378941/improvements-to-site-status-and-incident-communication#comment1266142_378941). Can the link address please be changed to https://www.stackstatus.net which works for everyone? (i.e. add www before the domain.)

Comment: Agreed, I am on mobile phone, and clicking the page without www does not even load the page, I get stuck on this question page!

Comment: I met this problem today at about 13:30 UTC, although the link was for http, not https.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yeah, for a while now (several months) it just happens sometimes, usually only for few minutes though, so no big deal. Best guess is DDoS attacks, but might also be downtime due to code build.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar The www version works for me right now while the non-www version (both http and https) still isn't working after more than 20 minutes. Oh well.

Comment: @AndrewMorton it's some kind of browser cache that has to be manually cleaned, I did read about it a little but honestly it's pointless to ask the users to go through such things just in order to see site that should show status. As long as the version with www is working it's fine, as long as all the links would point to it. :)

Comment: It actually currently links to **http**://www.stackstatus.net/, which successfully redirects to http**s**:// **www**.stackstatus.net/. I just tested this out on https://superuser.com.

Comment: @Justin nope, `https://www.stackstatus.net` redirect me to `https://www.stackstatus.net/` which is down. You probably have some extension adding www, or other magic at work here. ;)

Comment: @Justin another direction, maybe your browser doesn't have the poisoned cache, so it successfully redirects to the www as it should.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about the delay, we’re aware of several instances of `http://<no www>` and have plans to fix them [as described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381162/165455).

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks, this one already fixed by Yaakov though. :)

Comment: @Shadow yes I know, but people may come across this question as a result of seeing other links that we haven’t fixed yet (or from other similar questions, like I did).

Comment: @Aaron that is true. You have list of all places having links to stackstatus.net, or are you looking it case-by-case here?

Comment: @shadow there is a work item to correct all references en masse, a list that is easily pulled from git (there are dozens and dozens).

Answer (score 6):

The link is now fixed.

> app offline oh no!?!
> what's the network status now?
> oh nice! link works now!

Comment: Please take a look at this: [Change the HTTP status blog links to HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377087)

Comment: And this: [Read-only mode banner has broken link to stackstatus.net](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382215/read-only-mode-banner-has-broken-link-to-stackstatus-net)