# Read-only mode banner has broken link to stackstatus.net

Tags: bug, notification-bar, maintenance, read-only, stackstatus

The [banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh2HI.png) that appears on the sites when they're in read-only mode reads as follows:

> This site is currently in read-only mode. We’ll return with full functionality soon. Follow [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus), visit [our status blog](http://stackstatus.net/) or search [our recent meta posts on the topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance+or+site-maintenance?tab=Newest) for more info.

The link to stackstatus.net has a few issues:

1. It doesn't work: it links to http://stackstatus.net instead of https://www.stackstatus.net/
2. It's not a blog any more
3. The link isn't HTTPS

Ideally, both links would work (although HTTPS links are always good), but since the "www." is currently required, the banner should include it.

Comment: In the same banner, there's also this issue: [Link to "recent meta posts" search results in "read-only mode" banner contains redundant tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377249).

Comment: Related: [Change the HTTP status blog links to HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377087)

Comment: Thanks, we noticed this too and it will be part of the work mentioned here: [The StackStatus website does not resolve without a preceding "www" in the URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381162/165455).

Comment: Related: [Change status blog address to https://www.stackstatus.net/ in the offline for maintenance page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379587/change-status-blog-address-to-https-www-stackstatus-net-in-the-offline-for-ma)