# Dead link in "Offline for maintenance" page

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, maintenance, stackstatus

There was a brief outage today, during which I couldn't load any Stack Exchange sites. Eventually I got this webpage: [image: offline for maintenance]

The "status blog" link goes to http://stackstatus.net, which was a valid link back when the status blog was a tumblr blog. But today stackstatus.net is some other thing, which only accepts HTTPS (reasonable), and just renders an error page unless you include the www subdomain (questionable and annoying, but who am I to judge). As a result, clicking the link just makes my browser spin for a while before it gives up and renders a connection timeout page.

These error pages should be amended to point to https://www.stackstatus.net.

I see [Change status blog address to https://www.stackstatus.net/ in the offline for maintenance page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379587/change-status-blog-address-to-https-www-stackstatus-net-in-the-offline-for-ma), which looks very much like a duplicate question to me, but that one is closed as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), while I am clearly still experiencing the same issue. Maybe it was only fixed for one site, rather than network-wide?

Comment: Also maybe some useful info in this only tangentially-related answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382403/165455

Comment: Well, I can't prove it without taking the site offline, but the links on all of the offline/maintenance pages have been updated to point to `https://www.`.